# Paperclip fails to set attachment_content_type for files without extentions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm using rails 3 + paperclip + s3 (private bucket) to allow users to upload a file.

What's broken is user's can upload files w/o extentions like the rails gemfile which is just "gemfile" not "gemfile.txt" When you upload this file, paperclip does not set the attachment_content_type.

I'm determining the content_type like so:

```
self.attachment.instance_write(:content_type, MIME::Types.type_for(self.attachment_file_name).to_s)
```

Is there a better way to do this that is more reliable and solves for the above bug? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are asking MIME::Types to find the type with the file name given. It expects to have the file extension in the attachment_file_name (like `image_12.jpg`: the extension is `.jpg`, so `MIME::Types.type_for` knows thie file is an image).

**What you are looking for:**

```
params[:image].content_type # return the content_type
# assuming :image is the name of the form file field
```

A little bit of research:

> Return the list of MIME::Types which belongs to the file **based on its
>   filename extension**.

http://mime-types.rubyforge.org/MIME/Types.html + ctrl-F "type_for"